# Linphone: scripted events?

Tags: raspberry-pi, shell-scripting

I use Linphone to make direct videocalls to a Raspberry Pi 3B+ without any input on the Pi's side necessary. Out of the box Linphone does this good enough aside from a few hickups: the local (on the Pi) video-window is not fullscreen, and it would be great if I could run scripts on the event of a beginning and ending call. I want to control the TV connected to the Pi with CEC-commands to turn on/off after a call or switch back to it's last watched TV-channel.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Uh-oh. What are you asking for? An addon that allows script execution (would be OK) – or suggestions on how to script things (would be off-topic)? Tags suggest the latter… Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for further hints.

Comment: The first... I checked if there was some kind of signal that the client promotes incoming and ending calls, but so far I haven't found a docu. Is there really a plugin for this? :) And what about the video? Is there a hidden config to setup the video-resolution from the start?